# What are some really tough programming books?

Tags: books

I was wondering what are some really tough books on programming that would make me think. I'm talking about low level languages such as c etc and algorithms, points, functions etc.

Thanks ALot.

Comment: Most of the Wrox series is pretty chewy.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why are people downvoting? The OP just wants some books that would present him a challenge... it's not a stupid or OT question.

Comment: Hopefully they're tough because their subject matter is tough, not because they're badly written!

Comment: This is not a very good question. In particular, I think it lacks a clear criteria for judging books. "Tough" and "make me think" are pretty subjective -- we don't know you and what will be tough or easy for you. Or how it would apply to other people, for that matter. It also does nothing to inspire answers to explain why the books are recommended, potentially going against the [constructiveness guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective). Some editing could help, I think.

Comment: @Melanie - this is a "list of X" type question which will just get people's favourite book posted as an answer. If you check the answers *none* of them have any explanation of *why* the book mentioned fulfils the OPs requirements (well one does, but that's out of 10 answers).

Comment: I agree with @Anna and @Chris above, this question lacks key parts, such as explaining *why* these books are hard or how to grade books against each other.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Art of Computer Programming.  Donald Knuth.

Comment: I certainly gave up and decided I needed to wait until my university gave me a discrete math course. :D

Comment: Why?  What makes it so good?  Please expand your answer.

Comment: @Walter: What makes it so good?  It is definitive, complete and tough on folks who don't have a lot of advanced math.  You should look at it some time.

Comment: You should include that in your answer.  I have read it, but anyone who hasn't will get NO sense of why they should even look into your suggestion.

Comment: @Walter: I don't think I agree.  I don't think it needs any expansion.  The book is so toweringly important and so central to computing that I don't feel it needs explanation.

Comment: It's the book programmers are mostly likely to plan on reading someday.

Comment: Definitely the best answer

Comment: so _how much_ math does it really demand ? i ask cos its expensive and i want to be prepared before i jump in to something which _seems_ to be so difficult and so rewarding

Comment: @RYUZAKI: "i want to be prepared before i jump in to something which seems to be so difficult and so rewarding"  Don't bother trying to "prepare".  Just jump in.  When you find a subject that's beyond you, you'll know what you need to learn.  It's a life-long pursuit.  You cannot possibly be *prepared* enough.  You'll always need to learn yet more.

Answer (score 13):

[Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?tid=8570&ttype=2)

Not so "introductory" ;)

Comment: Why not (“so ‘introductory’”)? This *is* an introduction, used in CS 101.

Comment: @konrad: AFAIK, most university only use several chapters of these books for teaching.

Comment: Now I had to look it up, demolishing my laptop stand in the process (I use the Cormen as support for my laptop …). And you’re right. I forgot the latter parts of the book; these are indeed subject of later lectures (some in master courses).

Comment: @konrad: hery nailed it.

Comment: @konrad: sounds like an eventful process ;)

Answer (score 10):

[A Discipline of Programming, by Edgar W. Dijkstra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013215871X)

How to write provably-correct code

This it not a book to read, it's a book to *study*

Comment: steven i havent really looked into this book ; but it makes me ask a very critical question : is it of any use for say, a WEB developer or a C++ coder [device drivers,etc] or an Android developer ? I am asking you if it is worth my time ? [cont in next comment]

Comment: [cont from previous comment] i am new but i learn Wickedly fast. I read tonnes of blogs , Open Source code, etc. So is reading the above book (and others of its kind) really going to help me ? And friend; the only reason i have such pessimistic attitude is that i had read Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms by Aho et. all and to tell you the truth i have been hardly using that knowledge ..... but again i only have been programming seriously for less than 6 months. so what would you say ?

Comment: @RYUZAKI:  So you've been programming seriously less than six months, and you found the Aho et al. algorithms book not immediately useful?  Then you're not looking for the books mentioned in this question.  You might want to take some time and get more comfortable in the field and then come back to these.  The books in these answers (the ones I know, anyway), will teach you things and greatly expand your understanding.  They won't make you a better C# developer immediately, if that's what you're looking for now.

Comment: +1: And also David Gries' Science of Programming.  A companion book that expands on the themes.

Comment: @RYUZAKI like most deeper CS texts, you get out of it what you put into it. I got a new appreciation for the mathematical beauty of programming, along with direct experience designing and proving the correctness of very small programs. It took the better part of a year to work my way through the book.

Comment: @ Steven and @David Thanks a lot for your reply. And yes Design and ANALYSIS OF algorithms did help in understanding recursion; graphs; divide and conquer etc

Answer (score 9):

The [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) will certainly help you to understand low level concepts.

Comment: good one. i _had_ to study it as part of my CS syllabus and found it very interesting , challenging as well as enriching experience

Answer (score 6):

Seven Languages in Seven weeks will give you a lot to play with. When All else fails read "Structure and interpretation of Computer programs" One of the best books ever on programming.

Comment: "Seven Languages in Seven Weeks" is extremely cool but not  really a tough programming book.

Comment: If your goal is for a book to be hard for the sake of being hard you are right, on the other hand it is a book that has a lot of good information in it

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend [**Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific computing**](http://www.nr.com/).

A fantastic book, which details many useful scientific algorithms. Over my career in embedded and industrial computing system, one version or another, in one language or another<sup>1</sup>, has been my constant companion.

1. <sup>Prior to third edition, there were different books for different for different languages, so there were [Numerical recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), [Numerical recipes in Fortran](http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html) and even Numerical recipes in Pascal.</sup>

Comment: Wow, I haven't even thought about hat book in about 15 years

Comment: Yeah, I bought a first edition at university and have managed to find a use for the algorithms in those books in every job I've worked at since.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives to the well-known (and excellent) books already suggested:

- [Database Systems: The Complete Book, 2nd ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131873253) has a second part that actually explains how a DBMS itself is implemented. Has a lot of material on how to efficiently store and index data and how to actually execute queries in the database.
- [An Engineering Approach to Computer Networking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201634422) discusses the deepest details of actually making networks work. If you ever want to implement a high performance networking application or device, this text will provide a great fundamental background.
- [Approximation Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642084699) consists of an extensive overview of combinatorial optimization problems. The author advises to study the problems in-depth before trying to create an approximation, which is very instructive.
- [Types and Programming Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262162091) is 600+ pages of theory and implementation techniques dedicated to types in programming languages. It turns out there is an incredible amount of theory to deal with. If you ever want to create a full-blown programming language, there's a lot to learn here.

Answer (score 2):

Low level of .NET: [CLR via C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627048) by J. Richter. Worth reading if you want to know the core of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started reading [Hacker's Delight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201914654) (http://www.amazon.com/Hackers-Delight-Henry-S-Warren/dp/0201914654).  It might not score very high on the tough aspect.  But I would give it high scores on thoroughness, low level and clever problem solving, true to the spirit of it's name.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to learn Lisp langs. That will sure be tough ! Plus its a happy breakk from *regular* programming